# Pushing code from Maven builds into Eclipse plugins

Tags: eclipse, maven

Starting point: a heap of Java code built in Maven (and edited and debugged in Eclipse via the maven-eclipse-plugin). Desired end point: an Eclipse plugin that puts a UI around some of it. Question: What's the shortest path in terms of tools?

The maven-eclipse-plugin documentation suggests that it might have a contribution to make to the picture, but it's not clear to me that the functionality described is alive and kicking for current (3.5) Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Tycho](http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need "an Eclipse plugin that puts a UI around some of it" when there is already [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) ?

Comment: m2eclipse is not at all useful if your goal is to add functionality to eclipse.

Comment: Ah sorry! I did not realize that the end result is an Eclipse plugin itself.